# Falha na conexão TCP/IP ao tentar conectar a um banco de dados SQL Server

Tags: java, sql-server, conexão

O código que fiz foi um exemplo básico da Microsoft de como realizar a conexão. O driver já está instalado.

```
package connection;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.sql.*;
import com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver;

public class conexao {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");

        String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;" + "databaseName=pessoas;user=sa;password=root;";

        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);

    }
}
```

O erro:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Falha na conexão TCP/IP com o host localhost, porta 1433.
Erro: "Connect timed out. Verifique as propriedades da conexão.
Verifique se uma instância do SQL Server está sendo executada no host e se está aceitando conexões TCP/IP na porta.
Verifique se as conexões TCP na porta não foram bloqueadas por um firewall.".
```

Answer (score 1):

É um erro realmente bastante simples de entender se você tem noções de redes de computadores e aplica um pouco de dedução, ainda mais que está quase todo em português. Trocando em miúdos, a aplicação tentou estabelecer conexão com o servidor de banco de dados local (instalado na mesma máquina) e não conseguiu, ocorreu o chamado *time out*, que significa que expirou o tempo de espera pela conexão ser estabelecida. Alguns possíveis motivos são o servidor de banco não estar rodando, ou estar mas não estar aceitando conexões na porta 1433 (tem que ver a configuração), o firewall pode estar bloqueando (pouco provável neste caso). Tem que correr atrás, mais ajuda que isso seria suporte técnico.

Answer (score 1):

Tem que habilitar o TCP-IP e os ips,  adicionar no campo no campo porta tcp a porta 1433[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Iae Jader, tudo bem?

Cara, eu ja configurei desse jeito e nada. Inclusive eu fiz teste com outro banco e funcionou a conexão.